# While updating item, not saving changes from nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, nested-resources

Sorry for noob question, I'm just trying RoR, but I have an issue with passing to strong params (I guess) nested resources items.

controller:

```
  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to @product, notice: "product has been updated"
    end
  end
```

models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
```

view:

```
= p.fields_for :image do |img|
      = img.text_field :path
```

params:

```
"image_attributes"=>{"path"=>"1.jpg", "id"=>"13"},
   "category_id"=>"2"}
```

As result only image path not updating...

Please give me solution.
Thank You!

Comment: Add this to product_params:    `params.require(:product).permit(:category_id , image_attributes: [:path, :id])`

Comment: but i have:    
'def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :sku, :category_id, image_attributes: [:path, :id])
  end'